# javascript the http response not always returning every data

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

I'm trying to use webpack and make a map with markers after getting data from an URL (which gives the position of the markers). Right now I'm trying to get the data from the URL with the XMLHttpRequest object which is supposed to give me an JSON object but the data in it are sometimes right and sometimes some data are missing and I can't access the JSON object properties and I can't parse it because I always get a parse error invalid character at 1.

Here is the code from my index.js

```
function donnees(Jsonobjet)
{
console.log(Jsonobjet); //displaying the object in the console 
}


function main()
{
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=velib-disponibilite-en-temps-reel";
client.open("GET", url,true);
client.responseType = "json";
client.send();
client.onload = function()    
{
    var rep = client.response;//getting the data
    donnees(rep);
}


}

window.addEventListener('load',main);
```

Here is the code from my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCCSAssets = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

var config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: "./index.js",


 output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    filename: 'assets/js/[name].js',
    library: 'myApp',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', { 'targets': { 'browsers': '> .5% or last 3 versions' } }]
            ]
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/images/'
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/fonts/'
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.tpl\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['html-es6-template-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public']),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'assets/stylesheets/[name].css', chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Carte vélib'
    })
  ]
}

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === 'development') {
    config.devtool = 'eval'

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
      use: [
        'css-hot-loader',
        {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {
            publicPath: '../../'
          }
        },
        { loader: 'css-loader' },
        { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      ]
    })

    config.devServer = {
      contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      historyApiFallback: true,
      inline: true,
      open: true,
      hot: true,
      overlay: true
    }
  }

  if (argv.mode === 'production') {
    config.devtool = 'source-map'

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {
            publicPath: '../../'
          }
        },
        { loader: 'css-loader' },
        { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      ]
    })
    config.plugins.push(new OptimizeCSSAssets())
  }

  return config
}
```

and here is the code of my package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "mapvelo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --config webpack.config.js --progress",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server -d --hot --config webpack.config.js --watch",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.js --progress"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-es6-template-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "knacss": "^7.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54",
    "typeface-zcool-qingke-huangyou": "0.0.71",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

here is the URL for the JSON file I get sometimes which is the right one (use firefox to open it and get a better view of the JSON file)

https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=velib-disponibilite-en-temps-reel

I have been trying for hours to figure out possible causes of this issue but I'm currently running out of solutions. I want to know what is wrong with my code

Comment: Try calling `client.send();` after you declare the `client.onload` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work so here is the modified code in the index.js

```
function donnees(Jsonobjet)
{
    console.log(Jsonobjet);
}


function main()
{
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=velib-disponibilite-en-temps-reel&sort=-lon";
    client.open("GET", url,true);
    client.responseType = "json";
    client.onload = function()
    {
        var rep = client.response;
        donnees(rep);
    }
    client.send(); //I put the send call after defining the onload function instead of before defining the onload function
}

window.addEventListener('load',main);
```